# Can an action authorize everyone except a given user/role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Setting an action to be allowed by only a specific user or role is easy using the [Authorize] attribute. E.g.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ...
```

However, I ran into a problem when I wanted the inverse. Is there a way using MVC framework features to allow all authenticated users *except* those specified by name or role?

The desired usage would be something akin to:

```
[DoNotAuthorize(Roles = "RestrictedUser")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One fairly simple solution is to derive from the AuthorizeAttribute class and override its AuthorizeCore method, swapping its true/false logic.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Authorizes any authenticated user *except* those who match the provided Users or Roles.
/// </summary>
public class DoNotAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is effectively a copy of the MVC source for AuthorizeCore with true/false logic swapped.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext">The HTTP context, which encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the user is authorized; otherwise, false.</returns>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }
        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string[] usersSplit = SplitString(Users);
        if ((usersSplit.Length > 0) && usersSplit.Contains<string>(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }

        string[] rolesSplit = SplitString(Roles);
        if ((rolesSplit.Length > 0) && rolesSplit.Any<string>(new Func<string, bool>(user.IsInRole)))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a direct copy of the MVC source for the internal SplitString method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="original">The original string to split.</param>
    /// <returns>An array of strings.</returns>
    internal static string[] SplitString(string original)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(original))
        {
            return new string[0];
        }
        return (from piece in original.Split(new[] { ',' })
                let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                select trimmed).ToArray<string>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just list accepted roles and leave the exception out

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Admin, SuperUser")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Or create a special AuthorizeAttribute with that logic

Comment: Listing all accepted roles would work if the list of possible roles were finite. In this case, they are database driven and subject to frequent addition.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for those who will need it - very simply you can handle it using Policy:

Just add the class:

```
public class CustomRoleRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<CustomRoleRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var roles = new[] { "YourExcludedRole1", "YourExcludedRole2", "YourExcludedRole3"}; 
        var userIsInRole = roles.Any(role => context.User.IsInRole(role));
        if (userIsInRole)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Then add to startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...

     services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("ExcludeRoles", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new CustomRoleRequirement()));
        });

     ...
}
```

And then you can simply use `[Authorize(Policy = "ExcludeRoles")]` and all the roles will be authorized excluded `"YourExcludedRole1", "YourExcludedRole2", "YourExcludedRole3"`

Answer (score 1):

The following code simply negates the authorization granted to the specified user/role, effectively becoming an authorization to everyone but the specified user/role.

Use it just like you would use the AuthorizeAttribute class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DoNotAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) => !base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This is an even simpler take on my answer and automatically adopts future changes to the AuthorizeCore logic. I like it.

Comment: Supposing the user has not logged in or is not authenticated (regardless of roles).  Does this also authorize all normally unauthorized users?

Answer (score 0):

One way to authorize specific users and assign it to different controllers or actions: Make a simple static class and create const variables.

```
public static class RolesText
    {
        public const string MISDeveloper = "MIS Developer";
        public const string SuperAdmin = "Super Admin";
        public const string Admin = "Admin";
        public const string DistrictMnE = "District M&E";
        public const string PSUEngineer = "PSU Engineer";
        public const string Guest = "Guest";

        public const string All_Users = MISDeveloper + "," + SuperAdmin + "," + Admin + "," + DistrictMnE + "," + PSUEngineer + "," + Guest;
        public const string Without_PSUEng_DistMnE = MISDeveloper + "," + SuperAdmin + "," + Admin + "," + Guest;
        public const string Without_PSUEng_Guest = MISDeveloper + "," + SuperAdmin + "," + Admin + "," + DistrictMnE;
        public const string Without_DistMnE_Guest = MISDeveloper + "," + SuperAdmin + "," + Admin + "," + PSUEngineer;
    }
```

Then call these values like below.

```
[Authorize(Roles = RolesText.Without_PSUEng_Guest)]
    public class NeedBasedSMsController : Controller
    {
        private AUPDBEntities db = new AUPDBEntities();
    }
```

If want to assign different users then call it as below.

```
[Authorize(Roles = RolesText.Admin + "," + RolesText.Guest)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // YOUR CONTROLLER CLASS
}
```

Comment: It is a viable option, similar to the answer by codingbiz. I find the custom attribute approach to be more simple and easier to maintain since it doesn't require knowing or maintaining a complete list of possible roles.

Comment: Its just a choice, my one is just an alternate. custom attrib is good choice.